# Is it possible to use custom build cpython in Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, conda, cpython

I build a cpython locally (Windows) with a fix to a problem with multiprocessing that I have, but I also need data science stack of packages like numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlib, statsmodels and few others. When I try to install them the process appears quite cubersome for many packages and for scipy I wasn't able to resolve it after 3 days of trying.

I was thinking that it would be amazing if I can just replace python in my anaconda env, and use conda to install the packages I need. Is it possible to easily replace python with binaries I have or I need to wait while my fix is released with new Python version?

Comment: Have you tried literally replacing the Python binaries in your Anaconda env with the ones you built? If that doesn't work I guess the answer is to [build your own conda package](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/index.html) for your custom Python, then you can specify it when you create a new env. If the fix is a published patch then it might be worth asking on the [Anaconda forum](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda) in case someone else has already done this?

Comment: yes, I tried literally replacing the binaries in anaconda env, but it didn't work. I also saw the conda build command but I didn't figure out how to use it for python, and I didn't find an example also unfortunately. The fix was merged into latest python and backported to python 3.7 only today, so I'm not sure if anyone did it yet, but I will ask, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by replacing only python DLL that I had in, and the conda environment just worked with it